# Installing a PHP extension without restating HTTP server

Tags: php, php-extension, httpserver

How can install a PHP extension without restating HTTP server? (in development or in production environment)

Is there any way preventing from any server downtime?

How major websites do such changes?

Comment: Apache have `service httpd reload` - not restarting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache have `service httpd reload` - it's not restarting server, just reload config files.

Answer (score 2):

On Apache instead of "restart" do "reload". It will reload configuration and will not cause any downtime.

For others like Nginx or lighttpd I dont know.

Comment: lighttpd has to be restarted.

Answer (score 1):

> How major websites do such changes?

Major websites have more than one server - in cases like Facebook or Google, hundreds of thousands of them.

This makes updating as easy as setting the load balancer to not send any users to the server that needs an upgrade, doing the upgrade, and putting it back into service.

Answer (score -1):

On linux you can use *kill -1 < service name >* to have configuration to be renewed.